# Ошибка при работе с объектами в Object Pascal

Tags: delphi

Имеется следующий код:

```
TShape = class
  private
    FStart: TPoint;
    FColor: TColor;
    procedure Draw; virtual; abstract;
    procedure SetStart(x, y: Integer);
    procedure SetColor(color: TColor);
  public
    constructor Create(x, y: Integer; color: TColor);
    property Start: TPoint write FStart;
    property Color: TColor write FColor;
  end;

  TLine = class(TShape)
  private
    FPoints: TPointArray;
    procedure Draw; override;
    procedure AddPoint(p: TPoint);
    function GetPoints: TPointArray;
  public
    constructor Create(x, y: Integer);
    property Points: TPointArray read FPoints write FPoints;
  end;

constructor TLine.Create(x, y: Integer);
begin
  SetLength(FPoints, 1);
  FPoints[0].x := x;
  FPoints[0].y := y;
end;

procedure TLine.Draw;
begin
  TFrm.PaintBox.Canvas.Polyline(FPoints);
end;
procedure TLine.AddPoint(p: TPoint);
begin
  SetLength(FPoints, Length(FPoints)+1);
  FPoints[High(FPoints)] := p;
end;
function TLine.GetPoints: TPointArray;
begin
  Result := FPoints;
end;

procedure TShape.SetStart(x, y: Integer);
begin
  FStart.X := x;
  FStart.Y := y;
end;

procedure TTFrm.PaintBoxMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: integer);
begin
  isDrawing := true;
  SetLength(shapes, Length(shapes)+1);
  case instrument of
  1: shapes[High(shapes)] := TLine.Create(x, y);

  end;
end;

procedure TTFrm.PaintBoxMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: integer);
var
 p: TPoint;
begin
  if not isDrawing then exit;
  p.X := x;
  p.Y := y;<br>
  case instrument of
  1:
    begin
      SetLength(shapes[High(shapes)].Points, Length(shapes[High(shapes)].Points)+1);
      shapes[High(shapes)].Points[High(Points)] := p;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

При попытке компиляции выдает ошибки на месте обращения к массиву `Points` в событии `MouseMove:"main.pas(168,28)`

> Error: identifier idents no member "Points""

В чём моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Так видимо же, что у вас в выборе точек вот здесь:

```
shapes[High(shapes)].Points[High(!Points!)] := p;
```

непонятная переменная `Points`. Компилятора под рукой нету, могу предположить, что следует изменить на `FPoints`